# How does WP file loading work? How does it work when used in WP MVC plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, model-view-controller

I've created a video about one of the major problem that I have. I need to understand the file loading architecture, how it's done when writing a class in WP plugin development (how one class knows about the existence of another class), and how this compares with WP MVC file loading architecture. It's one big question, and I went through the various smaller questions that helped me arrived at the question summary in the video in the drive link below. I'm putting the plugin code in the Google Drive folder also: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JVSSlkSJ5pCfNojRh6jen3ax2w-HZr5d

Comment: Yes, my question is how does WP file loading work?
The video and attachments is to clarify the question, else, typing out everything will make it very long and I need to visually explain it, else, the question is too broad. I'm not sure how to condense it or make it better for this format, but I know I need help to understand this architectural question.

Answer (score 0):

## WP side:

- plugin.php has this line: `$wp_filter[ $tag ]->do_action( $args );`
- $tag = 'init'
- This calls `WP_Hook->do_action`, then `WP_Hook->apply_filters`

## WP MVC side:

- This then calls `MvcLoader->init`, which then calls the needed load_**controllers/libs/models/settings/functions** (only the files under the bolded folder names will be loaded)
- load_controllers will use the file_includer and make all files under the [plugin app path]/controllers be required
- This means that any class under the specified folders above will be auto-required for the plugin that depends on WP MVC [tested]
- This also explains why if one create a helper function, following the documentation, one would put the class under helper folder, but that doesn't get auto-loaded and one will get class not found error (because helpers doesn't get loaded/not in the list above)
- Upon a closer inspection, it looks like only classes extending MvcController can load any helper files (base class MvcController is the only class that has load_helper() function). The helper files need to be named xyzHelper, under helpers folder, and needs to extend MvcHelper. In the child controller class, call `$this->load_helper('xyz')` and the base class will automatically try to load the helper class from the helpers folder. The controller class will now have a helper object named xyz (the class name, including underscores, without the _helper suffix). One can now have access to the helper class through the controller class (in the view classes also, etc. Used like `$controller->xyz->function()`) [tested]

## How to get the above info:

- Activate an example plugin from WP MVC and navigate to a public view
- Put the breakpoint in mvc_file_includer.php require_file() [I actually just run the debugger without any breakpoint and there was a deprecated function warning at the above function. I didn't think to put a breakpoint at that function previous to seeing this, and I didn't know where to put the breakpoints previous to this realization]
- Look at the stack trace and try to understand

## Also, in WP MVC, there are other calls that will automatically include files

An example is `render_view()` - This will either call the controller's, or the helper's, render_view(), which will use the file_includer to find the desired file path, and call `require` on that file path. Therefore, it's more like this is a dynamic-loading of files that is being used.

## Now, how did `MvcLoader->init()` get triggered?

In the main plugin's file: wp_mvc.php, depending on if it's in the admin/public functionality view, wp_mvc_load_global_functionality is called with the needed parameter. One of the actions in that function is `add_action('init', array($loader, 'init'))`, which triggers the init hook for the MvcAdminLoader, which is a child of MvcLoader [tested by commenting out the add_action and it no longer works]